# Incorporate 3D model to HTML that communicates with database

Tags: php, html, mysql, unity-game-engine, 3d

I need to put a 3D model representing a rubik's cube on my site. I have already tried to create it with SPLINE 3D but there is no possibility to make the model communicate with the database.
My goal is to be able to change the colors of the cube directly from the site via the database. I have read that maybe it is possible to do this with Unity 3D but I don't know how it works and how it can convert to web format. If you know any method let me know, thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Three.js](https://threejs.org/)
It's a javascript library for realtime 3D graphics. The website has good documentation and even a simple editor.
Since it's all javascript, you can easily incorporate any requests from your database. In particular, you should take a look at the [Loading 3D models](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models) example in the documentation.